# Flex Builder 3 debug flash player fails to install

Tags: flexbuilder, flashplayer-debug

I recently upgraded to Windows 7 (not sure if that's related) and after re-installing Flex 3, I get the error that I'm using a non-debug version of Flash Player (when trying to run debug on a project).

That makes sense, so I go to install the latest version of the debugger, but when I go to adobe for it:  http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html  I get an error on install saying that it's not the latest version of Flash.  When I go to the link provided, it doesn't have the option of pulling the debug version.

Any suggestions?

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here:  http://blogu.lu/mrm/2010/03/uninstalling-flash-player-like-really-uninstalling/

worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Install the debug build for Flash Player 10 instead of 9 or the other way. That is how it got fixed on mine.

Comment: Yes, I tried to; I still got the error that it's not the latest version.